# Vector field transformation matrix from local (spherical) to geographical (spherical) coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-fields

Hello mathemagician folks and math enthusiasts,

I am currently working on a project that requires me to simulate electromagnetic fields from dipole antennas. I am working with a set of 3 antennas, all placed at the origin but each rotated around one of the cartesian coordinate system axis. The following link will help you visualize the dipoles' placement:

[A visual help showing the cartesian coordinate system with the local coordinate system of each dipole where the subindexes 1, 2, 3 belong to the dipole rotated about the x, y, and z-axis respectively](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLc26.png)

The field generated by each antenna can be viewed as a set of spherical equations, but to avoid redundancy, let us consider only the electric field in the $(\theta,\phi)$ coordinate.

For the sake of this discussion, let us define the following notations:

$\Lambda^{(\alpha)}_{\beta}$ is the vector/quantity $\Lambda$ belonging to the $\alpha$ polarized (directed) dipole, in the geographical $\beta$ coordinate.

$\Lambda^{(\alpha)}_{\beta_{\alpha}}$ is the vector/quantity $\Lambda$ belonging to the $\alpha$ polarized (directed) dipole, in the local $\beta$ coordinate of to the $\alpha$ polarized (directed) dipole.

$\alpha$ is referring to the unit vector from the cartesian coordinate system. In our discussion x, y or z.

The geographical spherical coordinate system is following the ISO 31-11, Misner et al. (1973, p. 205) convention, i.e, $\theta$ starts at z, $\phi$ starts at x

We define $R(\theta,\phi)$ to be a function matrix that enables us to convert data represented in local coordinates to geographical coordinates.
$$
    R(\theta^{(\alpha)}, \phi^{(\alpha)})=\begin{pmatrix}
    f(\theta^{(\alpha)},\phi^{(\alpha)})\cdot\hat{\theta} & g(\theta^{(\alpha)},\phi^{(\alpha)})\cdot\hat{\phi}\\[0.3cm]
    h(\theta^{(\alpha)},\phi^{(\alpha)})\cdot\hat{\theta} & i(\theta^{(\alpha)},\phi^{(\alpha)})\cdot\hat{\phi}
    \end{pmatrix}{}
     \quad 
$$
The elements inside this matrix are to be found.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    E^{(\alpha)}_{\theta}\\[0.3cm]
    E^{(\alpha)}_{\phi}
    \end{pmatrix}{} = R(\theta^{(\alpha)}, \phi^{(\alpha)})
    \begin{pmatrix}
    E^{(\alpha)}_{\theta_{\alpha}}\\[0.3cm]
    E^{(\alpha)}_{\phi_{\alpha}}
    \end{pmatrix}{}
    \quad\text{for } \alpha = x,y,z
$$

For the $\hat{z}$-polarized dipole, its electric field is naturally in geographical $(\theta, \phi)$ coordinates, we therefore obtain:
$$
\begin{cases}
\underline{E}^{(z)}_{\theta}=\underline{E}^{(z)}_{\theta_{z}}\\[0.3cm]
\underline{E}^{(z)}_{\phi}=\underline{E}^{(z)}_{\phi_{z}}
\end{cases}{}
$$\par
For the $\hat{x}$-polarized dipole we obtain:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E^{(x)}_{\theta}\\
E^{(x)}_{\phi}
\end{pmatrix}{} = R(\theta^{(x)}, \phi^{(x)})
\begin{pmatrix}
E^{(x)}_{\theta_{x}}\\
E^{(x)}_{\phi_{x}}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For the third dipole, $\hat{y}$-polarized we obtain:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E^{(y)}_{\theta}\\
E^{(y)}_{\phi}
\end{pmatrix}{} = R(\theta^{(y)},\phi^{(y)})
\begin{pmatrix}
E^{(y)}_{\theta_{y}}\\
E^{(y)}_{\phi_{y}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

The Rotation matrix derivation is where I have troubles. Any tips on where to start?